# Does there exist a set $A\subset \{1,2,.......,100\}$ with 65 elements such that 65 can't be expressed as a sum of two elements of $A$?

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist a set $A\subset  \{1,2,.......,100\}$ with 65 elements such that 65 can't be expressed as a sum of two elements of $A$?

I am not getting enough hints to start it

Comment: Hint: How many pairs of elements sum to 65? You would need to exclude at least one member of each of these pairs...

Answer (score 3):

yes I guess . A= {${1,2,3,....32,65,66,67,....,97}$} works.

Working- If $x$ is there , just exclude $65-x$ and anything $\ge 65$ can be included in $A$

Answer (score 3):

There are 32 unordered pairs which sum up to 65 namely: $1+64, 2+63, ... 32 + 33$. So such a set would have to contain none of these pairs. But this is possible: Take $\{1,\cdots,100\}$ and take out one element of each pair, e.g. $1,\cdots ,32$. Then there is no possibility to sum up to 65, but the set has more than 65 elements

Answer (score 0):

Since, $65$ is an odd number, therefore we need an odd number and an even number, both less than $65$ to get result $65$ by adding them. So, We construct the set in the following way,

Take all the even numbers between $1$ to $100$, so we have $50$ elements. Now, take $15$ odd numbers greater than $65$. There are $17$ such elements. Thus, actually we can construct a set with $67$ elements with the desired result. Here, the question only needs $65$ elements, which is quite easy to see.